# AS3 - To do list structure

Tags: actionscript-3, data-structures

I want to learn how to structure applications. So I would start with a simple **to do** list application with AS3.

This is my goal:
- Show every entrie in a grid
- Add / Remove entries
- Add additional informations to notes like date and importance
- Save entries local

Especially with the local read and write part I'm totally lost because of the flexibility. How to display the entries in a grid?

I hope for some tips or links to tutorials.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the MVC structure is one of the best way to develop applications.

PureMVC has very good support, it can be a good point to start.

http://puremvc.org/